# Prime faces validation for treeview

Tags: java, validation, jsf, primefaces

I´m currently exploring Prime faces, and I´m wondering how we can validate the selection from a treeview? With an for example inputtextarea, this is very simple

```
<p:inputTextarea id="description"
    value="#{createAdd.add.description}" cols="50" rows="5"
    validatorMessage="Max length is 25" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Description is required">
    <f:validateLength maximum="25" />
</p:inputTextarea>
<p:message for="description" />
```

Here we get valdation for the textinput using the required attribute and the  tag. But for the TreeView component there is no required attribute, and the  tags does not work.

So, given for example

```
<p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true"
id="category" selectionMode="single"
    selection="#{createAdd.add.category}" >
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

How can we validate that one node has actually been selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think validation has to be done in the action method of your submit button.

If I get it right you have two beans for your `p:tree`: the `TreeBean` and the `CreatAdd` bean. I assume your action method is in the `CreateAdd` bean:

If your submit button looks like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{bundle.del}" action="#{CreateAdd.doSubmitAction}"/>
```

Then you could check the selected value in the action method:

```
public String doSubmitAction() {
  if(category == null) {
    FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "No node selected", "No node selected");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMsg);
    return null;
  }
  // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I need. Sorry if this is a very obvious question, but I´m a bit confused from starting to use JSF, Spring and Primefaces all att the same time :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do validation in your backing bean.